# DC Motor driver with Recuperation Design

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, dc-motor, motor-controller

This is a design idea for a DC motor driver with good energy recuperation. I have a mobile machine, that includes a 250W motor with a heavy rotating mass and many spin up cycles during use. The machine should run from a LiFePO4 battery, and with this controller I want to recuperate the energy from the rotating mass as good as possible.

While the motor voltage is falling during spin down, it becomes difficult to squeeze out the energy, or I just don't know a standard solution for this.

So I had the idea to combine a step up and a step down converter function in one circuit, looking like a 4 quadrant current source, but used reverse. I assume 20kHz PWM here. This is the design draft I want to discuss:

[image: DC Motor controller with recuperation]

The half leg mid point, which is normally the output, is connected via power inductor to +12 from the battery. The circuit can step up the voltage and drive the motor with a voltage defined by the duty cycle of the driver stage. A duty cycle of 3:1 will produce 36V on the motor side.

The software can read the battery current and the motor voltage to estimate the delivered power, torque and rotation speed, and check for overloads. A battery current limitation must be implemented as well.

When the controller wants to spin down the motor, it reduces the duty cycle and the circuit acts as buck converter and recharges the battery. I can't overload it this way, because I have taken the energy before :).

If the power switch for T3 is turned off, the software must spin down the motor and the recuperated energy will flow through the body diode of T3, keeping the internal supply alive until the motor energy is at end. A warm goodby to T3 :)

My questions here:

1. Should this be implemented using more than one phase?
2. Can I improve this using GaN FETs here with 100-200kHz?
3. Are there traps I don't see?
4. Do you like the idea?

Please excuse my poor english